Why does the apparent precision of displayed floating point numbers change between Tcl 8.4 and 8.5?
I am observing an incorrect precision value with tcl8.6.6. This behavior change is since tcl 8.5. I have not modified tcl_precision. It's default which is 0 in tcl8.5 and tcl8.6
Here is the reference of tcl_precision https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tcl_precision
Based on above reference I expect the value -310.032 without modifying the default tcl_precision.
Please check below expressions.
tclsh8.5
% puts [expr -344.48*0.9]
-310.03200000000004       // Incorrect
% puts [expr -466.9*0.9] 
-420.21  //correct

Here is the result with tcl8.4
tclsh8.4
% puts [expr -344.48*0.9]
-310.032

I have tried with multiple tcl versions. tcl8.4 version seems giving correct result.
tclsh8.5
% puts [expr -344.48*0.9]
-310.03200000000004

Expecting the result same as tcl8.4
tclsh8.4
% puts [expr -344.48*0.9]
-310.032


@buran: Please do not promiscuously mark questions as duplicates of that question merely because they involve floating-point. The fact that floating-point arithmetic approximates real-number arithmetic does not cause the number of digits of output to vary between versions of a programming language, nor do the answers at that question explain this.

@EricPostpischil, the initial wording of the question was quite different (and shorter) than current version, when I voted to close it as duplicate. Also, the discussion in the comments show that OP still misunderstands the floating-point math constraints, discussed in the duplicate. I will retract my closing vote. I also expanded my answer.

Floating point numbers, as used in Tcl and many other languages, only represent some numbers precisely; specifically those that are whole multiples of some power of 2 (and within a finite but typically large range of multiples). The number 1.5 is such a number (3×2-1) but the number 1.4 is not such a number. This is a hardware restriction; decimal floating point is possible but quite a lot more expensive to compute (and infinite precision floats are a strictly non-production system as they're horribly costly due to involving infinite series generators). The result is that "1.4" is only an approximation (just as you can't represent 1/3 exactly in decimals; exact same issue in a different number base).
The way Tcl has handled this has varied over the years. Originally, it would internally immediately call sprintf() to convert every value to a string; the tcl_precision variable controlled how many decimal places were asked for in that. From 8.0 to 8.4, that operation was delayed until the string representation of the value was required. In 8.5, that was altered so that it defaulted to using the minimum number of digits to get back the same binary float representation when it was reparsed (this is what the 0 value for tcl_precision means). In 9.0, only the minimum digit string representation is produced; if you want something else, the format can produce it (emphasising that this is for display).
If anything is "wrong", it is your expectation that computers work in ways other than they really do.

Rational fractions work quite nicely, but only for simple arithmetic. If you have transcendental functions (such as sqrt or sin) then you need a more sophisticated approach.

Although I voted to close this one as duplicate, there has been change in 8.5.
Check https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tcl_precision

As of Tcl 8.5, changing $tcl_precision to a value other than its default value of 0 is deprecated. If you need to control the display precision of floating point values, use format (eg format %.12g $x).


The default value for $tcl_precision is 0, meaning that when Tcl converts a number to a string, the fewest digits necessary to distinguish a floating point number from its nearest neighbours. The advantage of this behaviour is that the string representation of an inexact number like 1.4 is 1.4 rather than 1.3999999999999999, allowing Tcl to maintain its EIAS semantics, and providing a more intuitive representation for script authors.

And official docs.
EDIT/UPDATE, after discussion in comments and examples of "correct".
So following code:
puts [expr -344.48*0.9]
puts [expr -466.9*0.9]
puts [expr -466.8*0.9] 
set ::tcl_precision 17
puts [expr -344.48*0.9]
puts [expr -466.9*0.9]
puts [expr -466.8*0.9]

outputs:
-310.03200000000004
-420.21
-420.12

-310.03200000000004
-420.20999999999998
-420.12

tcl_precision controls the number of digits to generate when converting floating-point values to strings. It defaults to 0.
Let's have a deeper look. Excerpt from official docs

The default value of 0 is special, meaning that Tcl should convert
numbers using as few digits as possible while still distinguishing any
floating point number from its nearest neighbours. It differs from
using an arbitrarily high value for tcl_precision in that an inexact
number like 1.4 will convert as 1.4 rather than 1.3999999999999999
even though the latter is nearer to the exact value of the binary
number.
If tcl_precision is not zero, then when Tcl converts a floating point
number, it creates a decimal representation of at most tcl_precision
significant digits; the result may be shorter if the shorter result
represents the original number exactly. If no result of at most
tcl_precision digits is an exact representation of the original
number, the one that is closest to the original number is chosen. If
the original number lies precisely between two equally accurate
decimal representations, then the one with an even value for the least
significant digit is chosen; for instance, if tcl_precision is 3, then
0.3125 will convert to 0.312, not 0.313, while 0.6875 will convert to 0.688, not 0.687. Any string of trailing zeroes that remains is trimmed.

Let's get greater precision with following python code
import decimal

print(-344.48*0.9)
print(f'{-344.48*0.9:.14f}')
result = decimal.Decimal(-344.48*0.9).as_tuple()
print(result)
print(result.digits[:18]) # first 18 digits

print()
print(-466.9*0.9)
print(f'{-466.9*0.9:.14f}')
result = decimal.Decimal(-466.9*0.9).as_tuple()
print(result)
print(result.digits[:18]) # first 18 digits

print()
print(-466.8*0.9)
print(f'{-466.8*0.9:.14f}')
result = decimal.Decimal(-466.8*0.9).as_tuple()
print(result)
print(result.digits[:18]) # first 18 digits

Output:
-310.03200000000004
-310.03200000000004
DecimalTuple(sign=1, digits=(3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 9, 1, 0, 8, 2, 7, 2, 1, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 9, 6, 8, 7, 5), exponent=-43)
(3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 9)

-420.21
-420.20999999999998
DecimalTuple(sign=1, digits=(4, 2, 0, 2, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 5, 3, 6, 3, 6, 9, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 9, 1, 1, 4, 6, 4, 6, 9, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 0, 9, 3, 7, 5), exponent=-44)
(4, 2, 0, 2, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9)

-420.12
-420.12000000000000
DecimalTuple(sign=1, digits=(4, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 4, 7, 4, 7, 3, 5, 0, 8, 8, 6, 4, 6, 4, 1, 1, 8, 9, 5, 7, 5, 1, 9, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5), exponent=-43)
(4, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4)

What this tells us:

the result of -344.48*0.9 - it uses at least 17 digits to represent the result, while still distinguishing from its nearest neighbours, in all cases (tcl with tcl_precision=0, tcl with tcl_precision=17 and python). the significant 17 digits, rounded up, because 17th is 3 and 18th digit is 9

It need just 5 digits to represent the result of -466.9*0.9, while still distinguishing from its nearest neighbours, both in tcl with tcl_precision=0 and python. That's why it is presented as -420.21 When tcl_precision is set to 17 you get exactly 17 digits -  the 17th 7, rounded up to 8, because 18th is 9.

It need just 5 digits to represent the result of -466.8*0.9, while still distinguishing from its nearest neighbours, both in tcl with tcl_precision=0 and python. That's why it is presented as -420.12 When tcl_precision is set to 17 you get exactly 17 digits, however the digits from 6th to 17th are zeros and 18th is 4. So the zeros are just ignored and you get again -420.12



Before wirting this question I have done the ground work. I have already gone through the official docs and https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tcl_precision. However, the precision added to the value is incorrect. its not changing it to its nearby value or something like that. It's adding unnecessary precision digits. With default tcl precision value should be kept as it is after calculation. If you calculate the expression you will get 310.032 only. Here, I am not touching the tcl_precision at all.

Then why this is not mentioned in your question and what else do you need as an answer (i.e. what is unclear)? The statement "incorrect precision" is misleading at best if you know what has changed in 8.5

Also for another expression I don't see this behavior.
% puts [expr -466.8*0.9]
-420.12
If the explanation you shared is true then this expression should also showing the similar value.

Read the duplicate again. floating math calculations does not mean that all and every calculation will be "incorrect" as you think.

updated the questions to avoid confusion.

I did not say every calculation is wrong. I have shared correct example too. Trying to understand the reason/root cause for the other one. I have tried another example by changing the tcl_precision but not getting value as per the new precision value. Can you check and explain this one:
% set ::tcl_precision 17
17
% puts [expr -466.8*0.9]
-420.12   //// even after setting the precision to 17 I still see the value upto 2 level
Please share if the results are same at your end too.

@crazyMinds: Re “However, the precision added to the value is incorrect. its not changing it to its nearby value or something like that. It's adding unnecessary precision digits.”: The digits are necessary. When -344.48 and 0.9 are converted to the floating-point format used, IEEE-754, and multiplied in that format, the result is exactly −310.0320000000000391082721762359142303466796875. However, the nearest value to −310.02 representable in binary64 is 310.03199999999998226485331542789936065673828125. For both of these, rounding to 13 digits after the “.” would produce 310.0320000000000.

… Thus, 14 digits are needed to distinguish the obtained result from the other value.

@crazyMinds: In the case of -468.8*0.9, the obtained result is −420.1200000000000045474735088646411895751953125, which is also the representable value closest to −420.12, so two digits suffice to identify the result.

In Tcl 9.0, setting tcl_precision has no effect at all (aside from being an ordinary global variable).

@chux-ReinstateMonica: Should have been “However, the nearest value to −310.032 representable in binary64 is −310.03199999999998226485331542789936065673828125” plus a “−” in the following sentence.
